# How to make this face look more voluminous, round and friendly?

Tags: modeling

i´ve created a lion humanoid with blender, but the face did not yet get the look i wanted it to have:

[image: my model:]

i have found a picture of a model in the internet with the right looks:

[image]

is there an easy way to make my model look more like the other one, by using some modifiers or doing something?

(ignore the errors at the eyes, i allready fixed them)

Comment: Enable proportional editing and pull or push vertices until you get what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic modifier to make your model look like some picture from the internet. You'll have to model or sculpt it according to your reference image. That can be very easy or very hard to do, depending on your skill level.

Comment: i didnt ever want to copy the picture i found in the internet
it just helped me to tell u what i direction i wanna go with the mouth